# How to authenticate fetch request with Google Docs API to download HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, fetch-api, google-docs-api

I am building a service that downloads the HTML form of a Google Doc from the Google Docs API and converts it to `.mediawiki`.

The following is the code for the project, but it fails to get the page I want it to fetch and instead fetches the HTML for the google login page. I have setup a Google API project and have configured the oauth2Client. How do I use my oauth2 credentials to make an authenticated fetch request to this endpoint?

My code:

```js
import "dotenv/config";
import express from "express";
import { google } from "googleapis";
import util from "util";
import * as os from "os";
import * as path from "path";
import * as fs from "fs";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// setup oauth

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
  process.env.REDIRECT_URL
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN });

const docs = google.docs({ version: "v1", auth: oauth2Client });

// Logic to directly download HTML version of Google doc. Need to add authentication to this.

 const htmlDocPromise = await fetch(
   `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=${process.env.DOCUMENT_ID}&exportFormat=html`);

 const fileData = await htmlDocPromise.text();
 console.log(fileData);

fs.writeFileSync("file_readable.html", JSON.stringify(fileData));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("App up!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In a  general sense, The [Google Oauth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver) includes populating the Google login page so the user can grant access to the required scopes, and then fetches the access token. That being said, your code is getting to the part where the login page is populated but the authorization flow has not been completed, so the `fetch` is only getting the google login URL.

In order to make this work, you have 2 possible options:

1. If you are working with a business paid account (aka Google Workspace account), you have the option to make an user impersonation with a service account and Domain-wide delegation, which handles the authorization internally (doesn’t pop up a login screen at all), you can find [more documentation here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java)
2. If you are working with a regular Gmail account, what I have done in the past is use the OAuth flow examples in the Quickstarts for Node.js . For example, below I will add one of them for a Google Docs Quickstart:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const process = require('process');
const {authenticate} = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

// If modifying these scopes, delete token.json.
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.readonly'];
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(process.cwd(), 'credentials.json');

/**
 * Reads previously authorized credentials from the save file.
 *
 * @return {Promise<OAuth2Client|null>}
 */
async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
    const credentials = JSON.parse(content);
    return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file comptible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
  const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  const keys = JSON.parse(content);
  const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    type: 'authorized_user',
    client_id: key.client_id,
    client_secret: key.client_secret,
    refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
  });
  await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}

/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
async function authorize() {
  let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    return client;
  }
  client = await authenticate({
    scopes: SCOPES,
    keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  });
  if (client.credentials) {
    await saveCredentials(client);
  }
  return client;
}
```

Replace your current Auth token management and give it a shot, this should suffice to have the user authenticated prior running the `fetch` so you can get only the URL you intended (the Google Doc url).

#### References

- [Docs API Quickstart - Node.js](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/nodejs)
- [Google OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#webserver)
- [User impersonation with a service account (*Only for Google Workspace accounts*](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#java)